# Como acceder desde cliente a una variable de Render

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pug

```
exports.nuevoproyectoPST= async (req, res)=>{
    const proyectos = await Proyectos.findAll();

    //console.log(req.body);
    const {nombre} = req.body;
    let errores=[];

    if (!nombre){
        errores.push({'texto':'Falta agregar algo'})
    }

    if (errores.length > 0) {
        res.render('nuevo-proyecto', {
            title: 'Nuevo Proyecto',
            errores,
            proyectos
        });
    } else {
        await Proyectos.create({ nombre });
        res.redirect(req.originalUrl);
    }


}
```

Como puedo acceder a **errores** desde el cliente
quiero acceder a erorres desde un js (public/js/app.js)
y desde ese js colocar un if errores swal.fire